# accessing nested firebase data in swift

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am working wth a data structure, and I am looping through a couple nodes and here is the json data I get.

```
Snap (20171012) {
"-KwM45HyW4UduQgKTGn6" =     {
    ImageName = "Screen Shot 2017-10-13 at 11.24.51 AM.png";
    fileURL = "";
    thumbFileUrl = "";
    user = "User not defined";
};
"-KwM4limD2aRyHgeKE5P" =     {
    ImageName = "test.png";
    fileURL = "";
    thumbFileUrl = "";
    user = "User not defined";
};
```

}

After this, I can access the "snap" value using my data.key to get the "20171012"

```
ref.child(myselected_spot!).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
            for mydata in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            {
                if mydata.key.characters.count == 8 {
                self.formattedDates.append(convertDate(stringDate: mydata.key))
                self.selected_dates.append(mydata.key)
```

How would I get the value for "ImageName"

Answer (score 2):

Your `mydata` is another `DataSnapshot`, so you can access [all methods and properties of that class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot). In this case you're looking for `DataSnapshot.childSnapshotForPath:`:

```
ref.child(myselected_spot!).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
    for mydata in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
    {
        if mydata.key.characters.count == 8 {
        self.formattedDates.append(convertDate(stringDate: mydata.key))
        self.selected_dates.append(mydata.key)
        print(mydata.childSnapshot(forPath: "ImageName").value)
```

Comment: So its, close, But I get a <null> printed in the statement

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple - I do not know what the variable `myselected_Spot` is but I am going to assume it's `-KwM45HyW4UduQgKTGn6`. If the below code does not yield results - I will need to know what that variable is.

```
ref.child(myselectd_spot).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.value is NSNull{
        //handles errors
        return
    }
    else{
        if let selectedSnapDict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {//Can also be [String: Any]
            print(selectedSnapDict["ImageName"] as! String) //We know it's a string
        }
        else{
            //null
        }
    }
})
```